# Why is my 'users_choice' variable referenced before definition?

Tags: python, html, flask, runtime-error

I have an HTML page `choose.html` with multiple buttons, each with the same name. I would like to assign the value of the pressed button to a variable `users_choice` in my Python/Flask code.

```
<form action="/" method="post">
   <div class="card_container_choose">
       <div class="row_choose">
           <div class="column_choose">
              <button type="submit" name="choose" value="Alex"/>
              <button type="submit" name="choose" value="Alfred"/>
              <button type="submit" name="choose" value="Anita"/>
              <button type="submit" name="choose" value="Anne"/>
           </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</form>
```

Currently, I have a list of names, `all_names=["Alex", "Alfred", "Anita", "Anne"]` ,and I am trying to match the value of the pressed button to one of the names in the list before assigning it to `users_choice`. After assignment, I reference `users_choice` in my numpy matrix.

```
all_names = ["Alex", "Alfred", "Anita", "Anne"]

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def choose():
    if request.method == "POST":

        for name in all_names:
            if request.form.get('choose') == name:
                users_choice = name
                break

         users_choice_index = np.where(user_board == users_choice)[0]
```

But, I receive this error message

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'users_choice' referenced before assignment
```

Indicating that `users_choice` was never assigned a value.
Can anyone help explain what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Why are you using a loop? Why not just `if request.form.get('choose') in all_names:`?

Comment: What does `print(request.form.get('choose'))` show?

Answer (score 1):

Variable is in loop making it unavailable globally.You should define it first outside of the loop maybe like users_choice = '' and then do what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a button can send a value.
Try to set values in form fields (maybe a select) and then only 1 button to submit the form. Or start using ajax so that you can assign ajax calls to any buttons you want.

Comment: Submit buttons do send a value.